# How to populate textboxes in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I want to show user's name and email in a HTML textbox. How can I provide value to the textbox from the controller?

I have tried this but it gives me Null Reference Exeption:

```
@model NamespaceName.Models.Account
<input class="contact" type="text" name="your_email" value="@Model.Email" /></p>
```

Comment: 1. Use HTML-Helpers or Tag-Helpers to render an input from a Model property. 2. Set the `model` parameter in your controller's actions' `Controller.View` calls. 3. Don't use Entity Types as two-way ViewModels because malicious parameter binding is a large security vulnerability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Null Reference Exeption` because of your `Model` object is null. You need pass `Model` from `Controller`.

In your controller

```
ActionResult YourAction(){
      //handle code to get Account
      var account = new Account();
      return View(account);
}
```

And in view cshtml you can use

```
@model NamespaceName.Models.Account
<input class="contact" type="text" name="your_email" value="@Model.Email" /></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tag Helpers to the rescue
New to ASP.NET Core is the concept of tag helpers which let you easily bind your HTML elements to properties on your ViewModel.

Here’s the simplest code we could possibly write to show our ViewModel’s values in input boxes…

```
<h2>User Profile</h2>

<input asp-for="Name" />
<input asp-for="Email" />
```

Preview this in the browser and there you have it…
[image]